# How can I check if a product is part of a grouped product (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, woocommerce

Currently my function only checks if the product is type 'external' before execution, how can I change the function to check if the product is part of a 'grouped' woocommerce product. Then echo the button which contains the parent product permalink which has already been configured.

This is how I would like the code to run (if product is child of grouped product - show permalink button)

I no longer wish to check if the product is type external.

```
function parent_permalink_button() {
    global $post;
    if( function_exists('get_product') ){
        $product = get_product( $post->ID );
        if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ){
            $permalink = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
            echo '<a class="button" href="'.$permalink.'">Compare Deals</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work but will have to test it.

```
function parent_permalink_button() {
   global $post; 
   if( $post->post_parent != 0 ){ 
       $permalink = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
       echo '<a class="button" href="'.$permalink.'">Compare Deals</a>';
    }
}
```